# Screenshots of an Android Device

Tags: java, android, ddms

I've found a lot of information regarding taking screenshots of an Android Device.

Unfortunately, none of the solutions explain how to get a screenshot of a device over TCP/IP instead of over a USB cable.

Is it possible to take screenshots over TCP/IP? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

When the device is connected, use `adb tcpip 5555` to have the device listen over TCP, then use `adb connect <device-ip>` to connect to it and use the DDMS tools as usual.

Comment: I need to take the screenshots programatically using ddmlib. Is it possible to do something similar to your suggestion? I found `http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.5/system/core/adb/SERVICES.TXT` but it does not say anything about connecting to a device over TCP.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to it is to connect to the device via ADB over TCP/IP. Then you can use DDMS as usual to take the screenshot.

Information on ADB over TCP/IP:

[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Comment: I need to take the screenshots programatically using ddmlib. Is it possible to do something similar to your suggestion? I found `http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.5/system/core/adb/SERVICES.TXT` but it does not say anything about connecting to a device over TCP.